# matching values is not recognized as matching

Tags: javascript, arrays

This has been driving me crazy for hours, have a look at this simple loop:

```
  myEvent.users.forEach( function( user ){

    console.log(user._id + '     ' + req.body.dogId );
    if ( user._id === req.body.dogId ){
      console.log('yay..');
    }else {
      console.log('no match');
    }
  });
```

Generates the following output:

```
      // 560d2cd0475f9ca012a7b2b2    560d2cd0475f9ca012a7b2b2
      // no match
      // 560d2cdd475f9ca012a7b2b3     560d2cd0475f9ca012a7b2b2
      // no match
      // 5613c6ee71dfaeac24371082     560d2cd0475f9ca012a7b2b2
      // no match
```

The first Item is a match but not recognized as such.
I´ve been trying several different loops with the same result.

I also made a hard-coded version of the Array:

```
 var arr = ['5613c6ee71dfaeac24371082', '560d2cdd475f9ca012a7b2b3','5613c6ee71dfaeac24371082' ]
```

That worked and generated the expected output.

But I can not understand why the 'real' version does not. When looking at the output i can´t see a problem.

Tips appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Check `length` of both strings, if differ use `trim()`

Comment: Try: if (trimuser._id.trim() === req.body.dogId.trim() ){

Comment: after checking on suggestion from Tushar...A tip ,try to use `string.localeCompare( param )`

Comment: That was a very good tip! 
Turns out that user._id.length is undefined. This means it is not a string I suppose?

Comment: is two ID's are string?

Comment: try, replace with two '=' in if statement instead of three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is due to the difference in the data types of the two values that you are comparing. The `===`(equal value and equal type) operator compares both value and the type of the data. Convert the Object type value to a string using the `String(object)` function before comparison.

```
myEvent.users.forEach( function( user ){

console.log(user._id + '     ' + req.body.dogId );
if ( String(user._id) === req.body.dogId ){
  console.log('yay..');
}else {
  console.log('no match');
}
});
```

Comment: And it worked! Thank you very much and thank you all for the comments above.